# ListenAndServe vs ListenAndServeTLS Speed

Tags: go, ssl, tls1.2

I'm building an API that will be hit with many requests/second from a few sources (call it 1000/sec) and will be responding to each quickly with very little information (think < 1k).

When I use HTTP (`http.ListenAndServe()`), performance is between 1000-2000 req/sec using Siege on my t3.micro and CPU usage rarely exceeds 30-40%

With HTTPS (`http.ListenAndServeTLS()`), I cap at around 450 req/sec with CPU usage at 100%. It seems pretty obvious it's doing a lot of SSL handshake type work, but my question is why would this be the case? Even with few concurrent connections from Siege it is much slower (I also tried connection=keep-alive in siege config)

I get that the first connection should be slower, but after that, is this behavior still expected or is there some issue I am not aware of? One thing I noticed is Siege is using HTTP/1.1, I would think it should be using 2.0 when going over HTTPS?

Thanks.

Comment: When you say "many requests/second from a few sources," do you mean that a few sources are holding their TLS connections and reusing them, or that those sources are generating a new TLS session for every request. Every time you negotiate a new TLS session, that's very expensive, even if it's a source you've seen before (that doesn't really have much impact). If you only have a few sources, they should reuse their sessions.

Comment: Thanks. I suspect that this is what my be happening with Siege (not reusing connections often enough even though I did set connection to keep-alive (both keep-alive and close in the siegerc didnt make a difference) but I don't actually know what it's doing. Yes, in practice a few clients will each be making many requests per second to the api. I will note that the average response time was something like 7ms (it's around 2ms with http) so it's definitely not doing a whole handshake EVERY request, but there's something I'm missing or doing wrong.

Comment: You will need to explore this on the client and server side, and watch the network traffic. I'm not familiar with Siege particularly. Ideally you'd move this to HTTP/2, which supports multiplexing over a single TLS connection. In HTTP/1.1, you will need to make sure that you pipeline your requests. If all the current connections are busy, you may have it configured to create a new connection (which is expensive) rather than wait for an existing connection to become available. This is a complex topic, and not trivial to address in this kind of Q&A format.

Comment: Thanks. Makes sense I'll dig into it more. I mostly wanted to make sure there wasn't something obvious I was missing.

Answer (score 1):

When using SSL/TLS your program needs to encode, decode each message sent or received, and this consumes CPU power. You may try to add http/https proxy which will terminate the SSL/TLS traffic. This can be apache http, nginx, haproxy. This can improve the situation.

Comment: thanks, but on second thought, my code is doing quite a lot between requests (looking up multiple values in redis, doing some string manipulation and computation), I can't imagine the packet encoding is adding that much overhead?

Comment: Using an external proxy doesn't improve that situation at all. It only moves it. In fact, it may hurt the situation.

Comment: @Flimzy, proxy can be on external machine.

Comment: @ManOnPoint, we talk about encryption and this always is quite heavy operation.

Comment: @RomeoNinov: Of course it can. But that still just moves the problem.

Comment: @Flimzy, SSL/TLS cost CPU power, this is cryptography :)

Comment: @romeoNinov, more power than doing multiple string.contains and splitting calls, pulling up 10 or so redis keys over intranet (elasticache) and doing other computations and logic, per each request to server  vs encoding around 200 bytes response? Seems unlikely . I will try to profile this later or find a better benchmark that uses http/2

Comment: @ManOnPoint, sure, make your profiling. And post here the result.

Comment: @RomeoNinov: Yes, And putting them on another server _still_ costs CPU power. This is common sense.